# Calling addItem on an empty JComboBox triggers actionPerformed event

Tags: java, swing, events, actionlistener, jcombobox

I have 2 `JComboBox` controls filled with items initially. Selecting one item in a `JComboBox` moves it to the other `JComboBox`.
The problem occurs when one of the `JComboBox` controls is empty. When I try to move an item to an empty `JComboBox` it triggers its `actionPerformed` event.

```
private void leftComboActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        Object selectedItem = leftCombo.getSelectedItem();
        leftCombo.removeItem(selectedItem);
        rightCombo.addItem(selectedItem);
    }                                         

    private void rightComboActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        Object selectedItem = rightCombo.getSelectedItem();
        rightCombo.removeItem(selectedItem);
        leftCombo.addItem(selectedItem);
    }
```

Why does adding an item to the empty `JComboBox` do that? It doesn't fire when an item is added to it when it's filled.
How to prevent the event from firing when it's empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following piece of code dumps the stack trace

```
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class EmptyComboboxTest {
  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        JComboBox<String> emptyBox = new JComboBox<String>();
        emptyBox.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
          @Override
          public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
            Thread.dumpStack();
          }
        } );
        emptyBox.addItem( "test" );
      }
    } );
  }
}
```

The relevant part of it

```
at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireActionEvent(JComboBox.java:1260)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.contentsChanged(JComboBox.java:1331)
at javax.swing.AbstractListModel.fireContentsChanged(AbstractListModel.java:118)
at javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel.setSelectedItem(DefaultComboBoxModel.java:94)
at javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel.addElement(DefaultComboBoxModel.java:132)
```

If you then look in the source code, you can see that when adding an element it will be selected when there is currently nothing selected

```
    if ( objects.size() == 1 && selectedObject == null && anObject != null ) {
        setSelectedItem( anObject );
    }
```

Changing the selection might cause the firing of an `ActionEvent`. If you follow the source code there is no mechanism to disable this. You could however disable your listener before you add the element, and enable it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

The way to avoid the `actionPerformed` event is to use the combo box's model, which is an instance of the `javax.swing.ComboBoxModel` interface.

E.g. the `DefaultComboBoxModel` implementation allows you to add/remove elements to/from the model. You get the model, work on it and, when the model is ready, you set it back to the combo box.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the selection might cause the firing of an ActionEvent. If you follow the source code there is no mechanism to disable this. You could however disable your listener before you add the element, and enable it afterwards.

//AB LUND PE CHARHO